# @class with protocol declarations underneath?

Tags: objective-c, class, interface, protocols

I am currently learning objective-c from a book. In one example, before the class interface of a particular header file, it reads `@class` followed by two protocol declarations.

```
@class Thing;

@protocol Foo
-(void)foo:(Thing *);
@end;

@protocol Bar
-(void)bar:(Thing *);
@end;

@interface Thing : NSObject <Foo, Bar>
...
```

I understand that `@class` is used to prevent circular references, however I do not understand what is going on below that. Why are the protocols declared there, rather than in the `@interface` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they declared normally or forward declared?

In the former case then it's just a declaration of a custom protocol, which is probably used by a class that is defined below (eg. `@interface MyClass : Object<MyProtocol>`. Otherwise it's a forward declaration needed for the same specific reason of a class forward declaration.

Comment: I think I understand what is going on now. My confusion was that I thought the `@class` statement and the two protocol declarations went hand in hand and had something to do with each other. 
@`class` was simply informing the compiler that that a class of that name existed, because a reference was being used in the protocol declaration. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's a forward declaration indeed :)